# Force Python Application on top of other windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

I am using Python3 and PySide2
How do I freeze computer and only focus and activate my small python dialog user interface on top of all running application ?

Here is my sample code

```
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

from gui import main


class MyUI(main.Ui_MainWindow, QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, maya=False):
        super(MyUI, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    client = MyUI()
    client.show()
    app.exec_()
```

> self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
>   |QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

With window Flags I am able to place my application on top of all application
but still users can use other running applications